# MySQL - Is there a way to use WHERE for two tables each?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get following data from my MySQL tables:

```
SELECT pupils.NAME, pupils.ID, teachers.name, teachers.id 
FROM pupils, teachers 
WHERE teachers.JITSI=0 
AND pupils.JITSI=0
```

But when I try to execute it, it just gives me an emty set. I want to have every single Entry from those two tables where the column `JITSI` is 1 (`JITSI` is a boolean). Do I have to use some sort of  a `JOIN` ?

`SELECT * FROM teachers` gives this result:

```
+----------------+--------+-------+
| NAME           | ID     | JITSI |
+----------------+--------+-------+
| Max Mustermann | root12 |     0 |
+----------------+--------+-------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

And `SELECT * FROM pupils` gives this result:

```
+----------------------------+--------+-------+
| NAME                       | ID     | JITSI |
+----------------------------+--------+-------+
| Annegret Kramp-Karrenbauer | etcbla |     1 |
| Anne Bauer                 | atcbla |     0 |
+----------------------------+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to solve this:

```
SELECT 'pupil' AS `type`, pupils.NAME, pupils.ID
FROM pupils
WHERE pupils.JITSI = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'teacher', teachers.name, teachers.id 
FROM teachers 
WHERE teachers.JITSI = 0
```

... or using a sub-select

```
SELECT `type`, NAME, ID
FROM (
  SELECT 'pupil' AS `type`, pupils.NAME, pupils.ID, pupils.JITSI
  FROM pupils
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'teacher', teachers.name, teachers.id, teachers.JITSI
  FROM teachers
) t WHERE t.JITSI = 0
```

... or using [`WITH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) (since MySQL 8.0):

```
WITH PupilsTeachers (`TYPE`, `NAME`, `ID`, `JITSI`) AS
(
  SELECT 'pupil' AS `TYPE`, pupils.NAME, pupils.ID, pupils.JITSI
  FROM pupils
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'teacher', teachers.name, teachers.id, teachers.JITSI
  FROM teachers
)
SELECT `TYPE`, `NAME`, `ID` 
FROM PupilsTeachers
WHERE `JITSI` = 0;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3d8c168d5a93b0f3aac95d2a1211b110)

Comment: Thank you @Sebastian Brosch!